# How to seamlessly convert one similar objects to another both compliant to similar interfaces in typescript?

Tags: oop, typescript, interface

I have two interfaces. One from backend:

```
interface IPrescriptionInfo {
    budget?: BenefitBudget;
    discount?: string;
    prescriprionDate?: number;
    prescriptionAPU?: string;
    prescriptionAmount?: number;
    prescriptionMedicine?: string;
    prescriptionMethod?: string;
    prescriptionMode?: PrescriptionMode;
    prescriptionNumber?: string;
    prescriptionRecordID?: string;
    prescriptionRole?: string;
    prescriptionSpeciality?: string;
    prescriptionState?: PrescriptionStatus;
    prescriptionType?: string;
    prescriptionUserUID?: string;
    protocolID?: string;
    recipeEhrID?: string;
}
```

and another one for internal data model:

```
interface IPrescription {
  budget?: string;
  discount: number;
  precriptionControl?: string;
  prescriprionDate: Moment;
  prescriptionAmount: number;
  prescriptionAPU: string;
  prescriptionMedicine: string;
  prescriptionMethod: string;
  prescriptionMode?: string;
  prescriptionNumber: string;
  prescriptionRecordID: string;
  prescriptionRole: string;
  prescriptionSpeciality: string;
  prescriptionState?: string;
  prescriptionType: string;
  prescriptionUserUID: string;
  protocolID: string;
  recipeEhrID: string;
}
```

How to seamlessly convert an object compliant to `IPrescriptionInfo` to `IPrescription` using Typescript powers without 'manually' assigning properties one by one?

**UPDATE**

Just to be clear. Ima looking for the way to avoid junior-style code like:

```
const prescription: IPrescription;
const prescriptionInfo: IPrescriptionInfo;
...
prescription.discount = prescriptionInfo.discount;
prescription.prescriprionDate = prescriptionInfo.prescriprionDate;
prescription.prescriptionAPU = prescriptionInfo.prescriptionAPU;
prescription.prescriptionAmount = prescriptionInfo.prescriptionAmount;
...
prescription.recipeEhrID = prescriptionInfo.recipeEhrID;
```

Comment: Why are these different interfaces to begin with? Or why do they not inherit from one interface? It seems like there are some incompatibilities, e.g. `budget` is a different type.

Comment: The reason is that some of the classes are generated from Java code. And it is not recommended to change anything in these classes structure. The ideal solution is decoupled classes structure and several adapters witch could be easily changed if something will be changed in generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is structurally typed, so if the types have all the same members, you can assign them directly:

```
let info: IPrescriptionInfo;

let prescription: IPrescription = info;
```

In your case, you face two problems. The first is that the `IPrescriptionInfo` is a weaker type than `IPrescription` (all of the members of `IPrescriptionInfo` are optional, so it could be a completely empty object). The second is that you require type conversions (for example from `number` to `Moment`).

This means that you aren't simply mapping the members (if you were, you could use the code at the top of this answer), you actively need to handle undefined members in the source object, and you need to convert values too.

```
prescription.prescriprionDate = (info.prescriprionDate)
    ? new Moment(info.prescriprionDate)
    : new Moment(0);
```

If you can make your source object more robust than a possibly empty object, you could reduce or remove the need to write code to map the data.